# How to retrieve javascript variable value with xpath?=

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract pricing and other attributes from this JS-Code:

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Rolex Cellini Time 50505",
  "image": [
        "https://chronexttime.imgix.net/S/1/S1006/S1006_58774a90efd04.jpg?w=1024&amp;auto=format&amp;fm=jpg&amp;q=75&amp;usm=30&amp;usmrad=1&amp;h=1024&amp;fit=clamp"      ],
  "description": "Werk: automatic; Herrenuhr; Gehäusegröße: 39; Gehäuse: rose-gold; Armband: leather; Glas: sapphire; Jahr: 2018; Lieferumfang: Originale Box, Originale Papiere, Herstellergarantie",
  "mpn": "S1006",
  "brand":{
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Rolex"
  },
  "offers":{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "price": "11500",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",

    "seller":{
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "CHRONEXT Service Germany GmbH"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively this code might do it as well:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.articleInfo = {
    'id': 'S1006',
    'model': 'Cellini Time',
    'brand': 'Rolex',
    'reference': '50505',
    'priceLocal': '11500',
    'currencyCode': 'EUR'
};
```

There is much more other JS code on the same page, so I am not sure how to adress this particular script with xpath.

I tried this:

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(.,"price")]/text()').extract_first()
```

but the response contains a bunch of values, while I am only looking for the price of 11500. Later on I would also try to get e.g. the name and condition.

Comment: Try `"""//script/substring-before(substring-after(., '"price": '), ',') | //script/substring-before(substring-after(., "'priceLocal': "), ",") """`

Comment: Getting invalid synthax. Maybe I am placig the code wrong: response.xpath('//script/substring-before(substring-after(., '"price": '), ',')').extract_first()

Comment: Try `response.xpath('''//script/substring-before(substring-after(., '"price": '), ',')''').extract_first()`

Comment: Nop, getting: "ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //script/substring-before(substring-after(., '"price": '), ',')"

Comment: @merlin please don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you solve your question.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options,

1) Using Json, but it would only works for the first case

```
json_data = json.loads(response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract_first())
price = json_data['price']
```

2) Using regular expression:

```
response.xpath('//script/text()').re_first('price(?:local)?["\']\s*:\s*["\'](.*)'["\'])
```

The `price(?:local)?["\']\s*:\s*["\'](.*)'["\']` regular expression means:

- Start with price with an optional `local` suffix
- Then single or double quotes
- Then `:` between zero or more spaces
- Then single or double quotes
- Then any value (price will be here)
- Then single or double quotes again

Answer (score 2):

For the first script, yes there is no better option than decoding that directly with `json`.

For the second one, of course you can always use regular expressions, but a cleaner and better solution I would recommend would be using [`js2xml`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) which transforms javascript into an xpath queryable format:

$ pip install js2xml

let's say one script has the following structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.articleInfo = {
    'id': 'S1006',
    'model': 'Cellini Time',
    'brand': 'Rolex',
    'reference': '50505',
    'priceLocal': '11500',
    'currencyCode': 'EUR'
};
</script>
```

formatting it would be like:

```
import js2xml

...

parsed = js2xml.parse(response.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first())
```

You can see the structure of `parsed` with:

```
>> print(js2xml.pretty_print(parsed))
>> <program>
  <assign operator="=">
    <left>
      <dotaccessor>
        <object>
          <identifier name="window"/>
        </object>
        <property>
          <identifier name="articleInfo"/>
        </property>
      </dotaccessor>
    </left>
    <right>
      <object>
        <property name="id">
          <string>S1006</string>
        </property>
        <property name="model">
          <string>Cellini Time</string>
        </property>
        <property name="brand">
          <string>Rolex</string>
        </property>
        <property name="reference">
          <string>50505</string>
        </property>
        <property name="priceLocal">
          <string>11500</string>
        </property>
        <property name="currencyCode">
          <string>EUR</string>
        </property>
      </object>
    </right>
  </assign>
</program>
```

Which means now you can get the information you need like this:

```
parsed.xpath('//property[@name="id"]/string/text()')[0]
parsed.xpath('//property[@name="model"]/string/text()')[0]
parsed.xpath('//property[@name="brand"]/string/text()')[0]
...
```

I hope I could help you with this.